# Error in Drupal 9 installation Deprecated function: htmlspecialchars():

Tags: drupal

I am getting only this error each time I go to settings for my drupal theme, it only shows then

Deprecated function: htmlspecialchars(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::escape() (line 424 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php).

How to fix this..I don't even know what it means

it is d9 latest build with adaptive theme

It seems to be the only error in my error log...the theme and site functions ok but this error popping up concerns me

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/monitoring/issues/3277649

This is a known issue with drupal working with PHP 8.1 or later. There is a patch with the issue and it may be fixed in a later release.